# Starting chrome in from batch file

Tags: python, django, windows, batch-file

I have django app that I am able to start from batch file.I want to start google chrome with address `http://localhost:8000/`.I tried with different solutions available but still the chrome is not starting. Server gets activated

My bat script

```
@echo off
cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Website\code\myenvironment\Scripts & activate & cd /d    C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Website\code\myapp & python manage.py runserver"


start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://localhost:8000/"
```

Comment: Strange quote placement.Try with `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://localhost:8000/"`

Comment: I have other batch file with `start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://localhost:8000/"` and it opens chrome properly

Comment: @npocmaka Even trying with quotes it doesnt open chrome

Comment: Open `Windows Task Manager` and goto `Processes` and kill `chorme.exe` and then try.

Comment: Even that is not opening the chrome.I have to run the command explicitly from a different batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can find `start` command syntax in [this documentation](https://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) :

```
START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
[/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]
[/NODE <NUMA node>] [/AFFINITY <hex affinity mask>] [/WAIT] [/B]
[command/program] [parameters]
```

So I would suggest to execute :

```
@echo off cmd /k "cd /d C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Website\code\myenvironment\Scripts & activate & cd /d    C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Website\code\myapp & python manage.py runserver"

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://localhost:8000/"
```